# Time is getting lost while casting to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, casting

I am hitting the Database and getting a table data using Spring's jdbcTemplate which gives me a list of Map of each record like below:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> tableDataMap = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForList(this.sql, new Object[] { isModel });
```

Now if I see the first map for LST_UPDTD_TIME column value it is:-

```
LST_UPDTD_TIME=2015-09-08 11:24:45.0
```

But if I try to cast it from Object to java.sql.Timestamp like below:-

```
(java.sql.Timestamp) mapRow.get("LST_UPDTD_TIME")
```

I am getting output as:-

```
2015-09-08 00:00:00.0
```

Can anyone tell me why time is getting lost while casting from Object to java.sql.Timestamp and how to solve this.

If I execute :    `System.out.println(mapRow.get("LST_UPDTD_TIME").getClass());`

> Getting output as: class java.sql.Timestamp

Also column type in database is TIMESTAMP(6).

Thanks

Comment: What printed if mapRow.get("LST_UPDTD_TIME").getClass()?
I meet some similar problems and I have to use new Date(x.getTime()). Remember that java.util.Date contains both date & time

Comment: What printed if mapRow.get("LST_UPDTD_TIME").getClass()?  --> java.sql.Timestamp is getting printed.

Comment: What RDBMS and JDBC Driver are you using?

Comment: Not an answer but have you seen [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)? I'm using it with Hibernate and it appears to be quite handy.

Comment: I had this problem when I called `resultSet.getDate("STARTTIME")` instead of `resultSet.getTimestamp("STARTTIME")` in my `RowMapper<T>`

Comment: What is the type of the column?

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the involvement of `java.sql.Date` which is a wrapper for `java.util.Date`, sibling of Timestamp. That SQL Date clears the time part, and is intended for SQL DATE.

If the driver thinks to yield a `java.sql.Date`, then the database probably has defined DATE for the column - a problem. Somehow that does not fit your error description though.

Check the `.getClass()` anyway.

Comment: System.out.println(mapRow.get("LST_UPDTD_TIME").getClass()); --> class java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: Column is also defined as Timestamp in oracle database.

Comment: Did you INSERT the value with a java.sql.Date.

Comment: No, I called SYSDATE function of oracle in insert query to update this field.

Comment: And the DB data are fine (?), though I would consider [SYSTIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions173.htm)